# Problema com o Split() no Mono

Tags: c#, string, mono

To usando uma plataforma que tem vários exercícios, a Uri Online Judge, e ele corrige automaticamente o resultado da saída do programa, porem é em Mono

Este é meu código:

```
        string a = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] temp = a.Split(" ");

        List<double> maior = new List<double>();
        maior.Add(double.Parse(temp[0]));
        maior.Add(double.Parse(temp[1]));
        maior.Add(double.Parse(temp[2]));
        maior.Sort();

        Console.WriteLine(maior[2]+ " eh o maior");
```

Em meu PC uso o .NET Core, e funciona sem dar erro, porém quando rodo no sistema da plataforma da esse erro:

```
Main.cs(10,31): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Main.cs(10,37): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `string' expression to type `char[]'
```

[*Link* do site com o exercício](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1013).

O Mono do site está na versão: 5.4.0

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

De fato, finalmente há uma [nova sobrecarga do método `Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) no .NET Core. Finalmente! Por isso sempre o recomendo. [Não há no .NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), e por isso não está no Mono ou .NET Framework. Use [o que existe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_String_Split_System_Char___).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        string[] temp = ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        var maior = new List<double> {
            double.TryParse(temp[0], out var valido) ? valido : 0,
            double.TryParse(temp[1], out valido) ? valido : 0,
            double.TryParse(temp[2], out valido) ? valido : 0
        };
        maior.Sort();
        WriteLine($" {maior[2]} eh o maior"); 
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nZH37R). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1hKxib). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitArgs.cs).

Consertei outros problemas do código. Uma das coisas que estes sites tem de ruim é que não avaliam se o código é bom e a pessoa pode acreditar que está fazendo algo maravilhoso quando na verdade está só dando o resultado esperado. Ainda tem outros problemas e eu evitaria o `Sort()`, prefira outra coisa, como o [`Max()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Double__), o que inclusive permitira eliminar a variável.

[image: Funcionar é diferente de estar certo - Fiat 147 caindo aos pedações circulando pelas ruas]

Comment: Eita, vlw deu certo aqui, sei que o código estava meio ruim, to começando C#

Comment: @YgorKayan veja a melhor forma de dizer obrigado em [tour]